# How can I achieve dynamic for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dynamic, combinations

I have to list out all the sum of multiple array

For example I have a 2D array with dynamic length and the inititial length is 2, but the lenght will change dynamically.

Each element length must be 3.

```
function addSum(){
    let length =3;
    //calculate all sum of two array
    let arrayGroup = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

    for(let i=0; i< length ;i++){
       for(let j=0; j< length ;j++){
           let sum = arrayGroup[0][i] +  arrayGroup[1][j]
           console.log(sum)
       }
    }
}


//result in console should look like:
//2 
//3
//4
//3
//4
//5
......and so on

Additional Info:
arrayGroup = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
1 st sum= 1+1 
2 nd sum= 1+2
3 rd sum= 1+3
4 th sum= 2+1
5 th sum= 2+2
6 th sum= 2+3
7 th sum= 3+1
8 th sum= 3+2
9 th sum= 3+3
This is all the sum of a 2-element array

if arrayGroup is 3 element array [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
1 st sum= 1+1+1 // arrayGroup[0][0] + arrayGroup[1][0] + arrayGroup[2][0]
2 nd sum= 1+1+2
3 rd sum= 1+1+3
4 th sum= 1+2+1
5 th sum= 1+3+1
6 th sum= 2+1+1
7 th sum= 3+1+1
....and so on, until list all the combination
```

The above code is to show how I get result of two elements, however when the number element in arrayGroup become N, how can I get all result of N element (i.e  arrayGroup = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],.......,[1,2,3]])?

Comment: Use `arrayGroup.length` instead of fixed `length`.

Comment: what does all sum mean ? what will be the output for [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]] ?

Comment: Indeed, we need a little bit more clarity here. Just like  
ashish singh proposed.

Comment: @ashishsingh Thanks for reply, I have added more info in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to compute is called `cartesian product` of arrays, you can read this term ( or you will find `cartesian product of sets` in mathematics )

```js
function cartesian(arr1, arr2) {
    const ans = [];
    
    for(let x of arr1) {
        for (let y of arr2) {
            ans.push(x + y);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}



let arr = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]];

let ans = [0];

for (let x of arr) ans = cartesian(ans,x);

console.log(ans)
```

also, we can simplify the code and make it shorter as well using some higher-order functions but try to understand the logic before going into syntactical improvements.

In short cartesian product is like multiplying two sets, what this code is doing is computing product for N lists by multiplying one list to the existing result at a time.

eg if you were to calculate a product of 1,6,5  you can do

```
ans = 1

for (let x in [1,6,5] ) ans = ans * x
```

**Also note that if elements will always be [1,2,3], there can be faster methods to calculate the final result, because then there is a pattern to output as you are not calculating the cartesian product of random elements.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful, but my main question is how to handle if  if the number of argument of cartesian function is not 2.  the number of  arguments may be 2 to 100 arguments. Can cartesian function handle this situation?

Comment: try to run it for your input and tell me if it gives different result from your expectations

Comment: @LebTim there's no "length=3" type of code in this answer, so it's not limited to a specific argument size.  What happened when you *tried* changing `arr =`?

Comment: @freedomn-m it will simply use the provided numbers in calculation. With this approach it doesn't matter how many numbers are in a set or how many sets there are, it wouldn't even matter if sets are different sizes.

Comment: @vanowm ? yes, that's what I said - did you mean to direct that to OP?  (LebTim)

Answer (score 0):

This is solution if I understood your question properly.

```js
function addSum(){
    
    //calculate all sum of two array
    let arrayGroup = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
    let length = arrayGroup.length
    
    for(let i=0; i< length ;i++){
      let arr1 = arrayGroup[i]
      let position = i+1;
      if(position < length){
       let arr2 = arrayGroup[position]
    
        arr2.forEach(a=>{
          arr1.forEach(n=>{
          console.log(a+n)
          })
         
      })    
      }
     
    }
}

addSum()
```

Comment: This code only handle 2 element arrayGroup , how about n-element arrayGroup which means that arrayGroup can be  [ [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3] ] or  [ [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] or any  length of the arrayGroup?

Comment: Here, I edited my answer.

Comment: It still only sum 2 arrays, the max number should go up to 9 in this example.